# How to navigate on Facebook using shortcut keys?

Tags: facebook, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to use shortcut keys to navigate on Facebook. I'm more specifically interested in joining a list of groups. So, I'd like to go to search tool bar, look up for the group, join it and then restart the loop again to the search tool bar.

I've come across this [post](https://www.facebook.com/help/156151771119453/) but it didn't clarify much. It seems that different browser *and* operational systems use different shortcuts.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need <kbd>TAB</kbd> more than specific shortcut keys. You can use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to hop between input fields and buttons on the Facebook page, or <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd> to go backwards.

So you could do it like this with the keyboard:

- Tab to the search field
- Type in the group name and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- Tab to the **Join** button and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
- Tab back up to the search bar to repeat the process

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your solution but when I reached my 30th tab hit I got lost... :( Facebook doesn't really make it very clear which field is selected.

Comment: @pedrez I agree, they could make it more obvious. If you're comfortable with JavaScript you could make a bookmarklet or userscript to do it.